# Finding $\lim\limits_{z\to0}\frac{\mathrm{Re}(z)\cdot\mathrm{Im}(z)}{\mathrm{Re}(z)+\mathrm{Im}(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

> Find $$\lim\limits_{z\to0}\frac{\mathrm{Re}(z)\cdot\mathrm{Im}(z)}{\mathrm{Re}(z)+\mathrm{Im}(z)}.$$

Let $z= x + i\cdot y$, then
$$\lim_{x,y \to 0} \frac{x\cdot y}{x+y}.$$

Taking along $y=m\cdot x$, then
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{m\cdot x}{1+m}.$$ This is clearly equal to $0$ , i.e. independent of $m$ . But what happens when $m= -1$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Are you really happy dividing by zero?

Comment: But at m=-1 the term goes 0/0 so the limit doesn't exist, right ?

Answer (score 1):

Even interpreting $\lim$ as "limit in the subset $x + y\ne 0$", the quotient $xy/(x + y)$ will take values arbitrarily big. Namely, for example, when $y = x^4 - x$ , $x\ne 0$:
$$\frac{xy}{x + y} = \frac{x(x^4 - x)}{x^4} = x  - \frac1{x^2}$$